# Laravel 5 TokenMismatchException on Multiple file uploads

Tags: php, exception, file-upload, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5 application, there is provision made for the admin to upload the product image and the product's pdf file. So, the form has 2 input fields like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Image File:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control input-sm'] ) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('leaflet', 'Leaflet:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('leaflet', ['class' => 'form-control input-sm'] ) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I upload the image and the leaflet both less than 2MB, it gets uploaded successfully. But when using, the leaflet more than 2MB, I get `TokenMismatchException at line 46`

In my `php.ini` file which is located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` I have the configuration like so:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2G

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 6G
```

The files that I am uploading are (**working**):

1. Image: Name: flower-1.jpg, Size: `51.6kb`
2. PDF:   Name: productInfo.pdf, Size: `777.2kB`

The files that I am uploading are (**not working - Gives TokenMismatchException at line 46 in VerifyCsrfToken.php**):

1. Image: Name: flower-1.jpg, Size: `51.6kb`
2. PDF:   Name: productInfo-1.pdf, Size: `5.00MB`

**The controller**

```
public function update( $id, UpdateProductRequest $request ) {
    $product = $this->prod->findProductById($id);

    $this->prod->updateProductOfId($product->id, $request);

    Flash::success('product_general_info_updated', 'The product general information has been successfully updated.');

    return redirect()->back();
}

/**
 * Coming from ProductRespository.php
 */
public function updateProductOfId($id, Request $request)
{
    $prd = $this->findProductById($id);

    $getAllInput = $request->all();

    if($request->file('image'))
    {
        $imageType = array(
            'product' => array(
                'height' => 347,
                'width' => 347
            ),
            'category' => array(
                'height' => 190,
                'width' => 190
            )
        );

        $imageFileName =  $request->file( 'image' )->getClientOriginalName();

        foreach ( $imageType as $key => $value )
        {
            $currentFile = Input::file( 'image' );
            $fileName = $currentFile->getClientOriginalName();
            $image = Image::make( $request->file( 'image' ) );
            $name = explode( '.', $fileName );
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/products/uploads';
            if ( $key === 'product' ) {
                $image->resize( $value[ 'width' ], $value[ 'height' ] );
                $image->save( $destinationPath . '/' . $name[ 0 ] . "-" . $value[ 'width' ] . "-" . $value[ 'height' ] . ".jpg", 100 );
            } elseif ( $key === 'category' ) {
                $image->resize( $value[ 'width' ], $value[ 'height' ] );
                $image->save( $destinationPath . '/' . $name[ 0 ] . "-" . $value[ 'width' ] . "-" . $value[ 'height' ] . ".jpg", 100 );
            }
        }
        $getAllInput['image'] = $imageFileName;
    }

    if($request->file('leaflet'))
    {
        $currentFile = Input::file( 'leaflet' );
        $fileName = $currentFile->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/leaflets/products/uploads';

        $currentFile->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $getAllInput['leaflet'] = $fileName;
    }
    return $prd->update($getAllInput);
}
```

**Edit 1:**
I am using `Form Model Binding`, so both `create` and `edit` file has the same form:

```
<div class="container">
    @include('errors.list')

    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'files' => true]) !!}
        @include('admin.products.product_general_form', ['submitButtonText' => 'Add Product'])
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:**
Just for the information, I am using LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64-bit architecture. It's a localhost. I have not hosted the application yet.

Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code where you open your form in your view please?

Comment: do you use Former to handle your forms? I can't understand how it would be possible for you to upload your file up tu 2 MB, but no more. What web server do you use here? (sorry for answering a bit late)

Comment: Did you try something like `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` to check that your max upload filesize has been properly setted by the conf file?

Comment: @YoannChambonnet you can check the update that I made.

Comment: ok, can you try my previous comment about the `ini_get`?

Comment: I had a similar problem and I was breaking my head because sometimes the tokens where different and the problem was that I had misplaced a `@stop` somewhere in a view.
Did you check manually if the tokens match?

Comment: @koox00 How do I check it ?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and was able to solve it by increasing the UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE and POST_MAX_SIZE PHP settings. The former should be bigger than the individual files you are uploading and the latter should be bigger than the total of the two (or more) files that are being uploaded.

There's a better explanation of what this does to the $_POST variable which leads to this presenting as a token mismatch exception here:

http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files

Hopefully this works for you if you haven't solved this already!

Comment: POST_MAX_SIZE was the culprit for me.

Answer (score -3):

Add ***{!! csrf_token() !!}*** within your form to generate a CSRF token.

`{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'files' => true]) !!}
        @include('admin.products.product_general_form', ['submitButtonText' => 'Add Product'])
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
    {!! Form::close() !!}`

Currently while submitting your form, there is no CSRF token provided which Laravel asks for because of the **VerifyCsrfToken.php** middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your input Sir, but I would ask you to read my question again. because I have clearly said that files below 2MB are getting uploaded while bigger than that, throws the `TokenMismatchException`. And just for your information, the `HTML Form Facade` includes the `_token` by default.

Comment: Have you increased the max_execution_time in your php configuration?

Comment: And why you think I need to increase the max_execution_time in my php configuration ?

Comment: As you are uploading a large file, the script execution may need more time to process uploading the whole file.